# PointerReleased not working outside of UWP control

Tags: uwp

I have a drawn object I can move around inside of a control.

The events, PointerPressed, PointerMoved, and PointerReleased captures the movement of the mouse inside of the control.

Though as soon as I move the cursor outside of the control, the events no longer gets fired. This wasn't the same behavior with WinForms, which is what I was used to.

I need a way to keep moving the object around inside the control while the mouse may be outside of the control and/or window.

I can't believe I haven't found anyone else as frustrated as I've been, trying to find a simple answer. I don't believe Microsoft wouldn't have thought of this and made a straight forward solution :(

Here is what I've tried so far:

```cs
private Point _previousDraggingPoint;
private bool _isMovingImage;

private void canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _previousDraggingPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement).Position;

    _isMovingImage = true;
}

private void canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isMovingImage = false;
}

private void canvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isMovingImage)
        _depiction.MoveImageToPoint(_previousDraggingPoint, e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement).Position);

    _previousDraggingPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement).Position;
}
```

Comment: You have gotten the expected behavior, [UIElement.PointerPressed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed?view=winrt-20348) indicates this event occurs when the pointer device initiates a Press action within this element. Similarly, other pointer events also take this way. Besides, you mentioned you want to move this drawn object inside the control, for that, why do you want to get the mouse location outside the control? This will make the object move outside of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [UIElement.CapturePointer(Pointer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.capturepointer) to capture the `Pointer` on the `PointerPressed` event.

The pointer can only be captured if it is in a pressed state.

```cs
sender.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
```

Do note though.

> Once captured, only the element that has capture will fire pointer-related events.

Thus remember to release the capture once it is no longer needed, e.g. on `PointerReleased`

```cs
sender.ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
```